# Best place to store files such as pdfs to include on product pages?

Tags: magento2

I want to store PDFs that can be opened up from product pages, where would the best location be to store them?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have links to download the files you should place them in a subfolder inside the `pub/media` folder.

Comment: Perfect, just wanted confirmation.

Comment: I used this and now I'm getting file not found/not allowed? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just place on pub/media/pdf :) easy question